# Background image for the scopes

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes

is it possible to change the white background image for the scopes and system settings and use for example the same image as the lockscreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. As Above, but you can do it directly from your phone. On your phone download and install Terminal.
Ensure your photo is in your Pictures folder as a .png file.
Run terminal (it will ask for a password which is your phone PIN as is also the sudo password).
Type in:
sudo mount -o remount,rw /

This makes the file system writable.

Then as the previous answer:

sudo mv /home/phablet/Pictures/yourimage.png /usr/share/unity8/Dash/graphics/paper_portrait\@27.png

Then the following command:

sudo mount -o remount,ro /

Restart the phone and your personalised background is there.

I am new to this too, so thanks to Kowal7 for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible.

You're gonna need adb installed on a desktop ubuntu machine.

`sudo apt-get install phablet-tools`

Then, do this to make the system files writable (note: there may be security concerns to doing this):

`phablet-config writable-image`

(Note: Your device will reboot.)

After your device reboots, you will be able to access a full linux command line for your phone by doing :

`adb shell`

Now we will replace the default white background file with our own file. At this point, you should drag your own image file into the Pictures folder the normal gui way from your desktop. Make sure its a png file.

Then do the following command from adb shell:

`sudo mv /home/phablet/Pictures/yourimage.png /usr/share/unity8/Dash/graphics/paper_portrait\@27.png`

It asks for a password, which will be your pin to enter the phone. After running this command, reboot the phone.

That's it. If anyone has an easier way, I'd love to hear it.